# Node.js: Should I discard request on error?

Tags: node.js, error-handling

When I build server using Node.js. Requests can sometimes fail. For example, there can be error in parsing POST data. When any error happens:

- should I continue handling the request and risk that some of those POST data may be corrupt or missing and respond as if nothing happened (or respond and notify the user, that some error happened)?
- try to reparse POST data (and if it fails for, let's say, 3 times, stop trying, add error to error log and show error page to user)?
- stop the request handling immediately and throw 500 error?

What is the best way?

Comment: How would re-parsing post data help? You have the data you have.

Comment: Is is possible, that while those data were loading and parsing, something else was run between in (between parts) and did something with variables,..., which messed it up. So, parsing it second time could help.

Comment: You have a system in place that arbitrarily modifies request parameters during request processing?!

Comment: Nope, but, while recieving data, the thread could be used by some other part of the code, which could accidentally mess up some variables. That's why I think that retrying could work.

Comment: A thread will mess up a request's parameters?! What kind of system would even do that?

Comment: As I said, it probably won't happen. Better safe than sorry.

Comment: So you're saying it's reasonable to attempt parameter parsing a few times on the off-chance that you've deployed a pathological system that might screw up arbitrary requests in arbitrary ways? Are  you building that redundancy into every aspect of the codebase?!

Comment: Well, it is done so. For example, Heroku (Node.js hosting) will try to launch your app 3 times (I think) and if it throws error every time, it stops trying.

Comment: That is a *significantly* different situation than pretending a rogue process is going to reach in to your request handling.

Answer (score 0):

The key questions to ask yourself in this situation are IMO:

1. do I know why the error happened;
2. can I recover from it?

The answers depend solely on your application. Generally, retrying something only makes sense if you can expect a different outcome with the next attempt. This typically applies to various *unexpected* errors when integrating with external systems. On the other hand, if the error that you get clearly states that it received e.g. a bad request, or that a file does not exist, then this is probably not going to change no matter how many times you retry the same operation.

If your business rules allow you to continue the operation while ignoring the error entirely, then do so. If your business rules allow you to carry out the request partially and you're able to report the partial failure - then do so. If the error prevents any processing of the request whatsoever, then you'll have to terminate it and report back to the user.

It seems to me that you had a particular situation in mind, so let me address request body re-parsing. In a proper system doing this **should** be utterly pointless - if you expect different outcomes, then there is something fundamentally wrong with your setup because the body of a request **should not change once it's received**. Your application should never modify request data in any way.

As a more general rule - if you expect that something unexpected might happen in your application, but you have no idea when, why or how, then there is something wrong with how the application is structured / executed. You should own your code and know exactly what it does.

Comment: I realise this is a really old question, but I felt like mr. Dave reacted a bit too harshly to what seemed like a newbie question and since I stumbled upon this post, I decided to answer it. Hope this helps someone in the future : ]